# How do I export 180º stereoscopic VR footage as "normal" monoscopic video for consumption by normal video players

Tags: conversion, vr

The title sums up the quest.  I am assuming I can do this with Premiere Pro somehow but if I need to use some other method, I'm fine with that as well.

An example of what I imagine I want to do:  I have footage from my Canon R5C using the VR dual fisheye lens.  This produces dual fisheye video.  I converted it in the EOS VR Utility to rectilinear and loaded it into Premiere Pro.  I hit the "Toggle VR Video Display" and I get a flat square render with two controls for the camera angle (which I assume I can key frame).  What I'd like to do is to export a video with this rendering -- just a flat "normal" monoscopic render without the VR effect so that people can watch it without a VR headset.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a program that can do this, but it's not an automatic process, you have to adjust it to frame what you want to see, just like when you move the head with the headset.

https://vongoob9.gitlab.io/vr2normal

Comment: I'm currently between projects and I will likely not get back to this until March or April.  There is also a [YouTube video by Hugh Hou](https://youtu.be/n2Hc2ZQbUik?si=qG5A_nHkcnVthc1P) that says he does it but I haven't watched it yet.